# CSS Animations how to transition from animation to a resting state

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

Here's my code:

https://jsbin.com/hibiviwuki/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
card
  background red
  border 1px solid black
  width 40px
  height 40px
  margin 20px
  display block
  transition 2s
  filter drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)) drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px green)
  transform scale(1) rotate(0)

  &.active
    animation randanims 2s
    animation-iteration-count infinite
    animation-direction alternate


@keyframes randanims
  0%
    transform scale(2) rotate(180deg)
    filter drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px green)

  50%
    transform translate(20px) scale(.5) rotate(0deg)
    filter drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px green)

  100%
    transform scale(2) rotate(-180deg)
    filter drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px green)
```

I'm trying to get this to transition to a resting position smoothly onclick in 2s. Right now it jumps from the animated state to the state without  animations.

Is this possible without taking control of the animation in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('card').click(function () {
      // Add animation class
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      
      // Listen to animation end event
      $(this).one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
        
        // Remove the class
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
    });
});
```

```css
/* https://jsbin.com/yujacagero/1/edit?html,css,js,output */

card {
  background: #f00;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px #008000);
  transform: scale(1) rotate(0);
}
card.active {
  animation: randanims 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
@-moz-keyframes randanims {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(20px) scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(-180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px #008000);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes randanims {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(20px) scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(-180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px #008000);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes randanims {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(20px) scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(-180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px #008000);
  }
}
@keyframes randanims {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  25% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(20px) scale(0.5) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  75% {
    transform: scale(2) rotate(-180deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(1rem 1rem 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -5px 12px #008000);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);
    filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) drop-shadow(0 -1px 2px #008000);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <card></card>
  <card class="active"></card>
</body>

</html>
```

[Updated JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yepibocane/1/edit?html,css,js,output) with Stylus

Comment: Thanks while this answers the question it's a bit tough for me because the animation is not aware of the end state. Trying to bridge together a bunch of different components.

Comment: On the end of the animation, you could add your next animation class. If you could provide additional HTML/animation someone may have a better solution